# fancybox implementation problems, "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Im trying to implement fancybox 2.15 and i don't get any errors but when i try to write any jquery code calling the plugin it gives me this error: "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

The code im trying is this:

```
$("#fancybox").fancybox();
```

and this is my html:

```
<div class="fancybox" id="fancybox" style="display: none;">
                    Användarnamn: <input type="text" />
                    Lösenord: <input type="password" />
    </div>
```

Im loading 5 fancybox.js files:

```
jquery.fancybox.js
jquery.fancybox-buttons.js
jquery.fancybox-media.js
jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js
jquery.fancybox.pack.js
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: Is the contents' of `#fancybox` what you want to open in fancybox? because if you bind that selector to fancybox, you are turning it into the trigger and the target of fancybox. BTW, you either use `jquery.fancybox.js` or `jquery.fancybox.pack.js` BUT NOT BOTH! ... it might be the cause of your js error

Comment: yes i want to open #fancybox 
How do i do it if i want it to open upon page-load?
Okej so i should delete one of them? I just downloaded it with nuget in the visual studio so i thought i should use them all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the contents of the container `#fancybox` on page load, use this code and target the ID of your hidden `DIV`

```
$.fancybox({
    href: "#fancybox"
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/K8w8u/1/)**

**NOTE**:

You either use *jquery.fancybox.js* or *jquery.fancybox.pack.js* but not both (the uncompressed version is meant for you to see the source code while the pack version, which is smaller in size, to be used in your production site)